# GCC v/s Visual studio run time differences

Tags: visual-c++, gcc

I have written a C++ code for a vehicle routing project. On my dell laptop I have both Ubuntu and Windows 7 installed. When i run my code in a gcc compiler on UNIX platform it runs at least 10x faster than the exact same code on Visual C++ 2010 on the windows OS (both of them  on the same machine). This is not just for one particular code, turns out this happens for almost every C++ code i have been using.

I am assuming there is an explanation to such a large differences in runtimes and why gcc out performs visual C++ run time wise. Could anyone enlighten me on this?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the release build on Windows ?

Comment: If you're using the exact same code on both Windows and Linux, you're probably using Windows simulations of Unix (Linux) system calls rather than using the Windows APIs directly.  This could account for the difference (or, at least, some of the difference).

Comment: isn't it because you are running normal command (compiled binary) in linux, while you are executing the program in visual studio (under windows), which of course needs much more resources ?

Comment: @xhudik - I agree, but could you elaborate on what kind of resources does visual studio uses and gcc doesn't? Does Visual studio run additional processes (which may or may not be necessary to execute the code)?

Comment: @cosmo17 I suppose you have dual-boot. I'm not using Visual Studio (VS), so I can say only this: running code in VS means that the program is wrapped by different layers (debugger, code checker,...) In order to compare gcc and VS (which should be similar) you should remove all not-needed libraries during code compilation, build project, exit VS and then run it as a standalone app. Then execution times on win and linux should be the same. (maybe there is different problem - hard to say)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, both compilers are fairly equal, but you have to watch out for a few things: 
 1. Visual Studio defaults to stack-checking on, which means that every function starts with a small amount of "memset" and ends with a small amount of "memcmp". Turn that off if you want performance - it's great for catching when you write to the 11th element of a ten element array. 
 2. Visual studio does buffer overflow checking. Again, this can add a significant amount of time to the execution.

See: [Visual Studio Runtime Checks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wtf2dfz.aspx)

I believe these are normally enabled in debug mode, but not in release builds, so you should get similar results from release builds and -O2 or -O3 optimized builds on gcc.

If this doesn't help, then perhaps you can give us a small (compilable) example, and the respective timings.